# Enum processes connected to internet in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, process

anybody knows how to list the IPs and the associated process with each one like that of "netstat -a -n -b" in cmd or "netstat -o" to get the pid

i've searched and searched and found the API that can do it but unfortuantely it is documentated with c++ and i need it in VB6 or VB.NET

GetTcpTable2
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408406(v=vs.85).aspx

GetOwnerModuleFromTcpEntry
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366003(v=vs.85).aspx

please if there is away to get the process handle or id in vb code tell me
thanks

Comment: have you tried the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

A Google search doesn't seem to bring up much with regards to these API's, but I was able to find [this article on allapi.mentalis.org](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetTcpTable.shtml) that talks about the `GetTcpTable` function from the IP Helper API (`iphlpapi.dll`) with some example code for VB6.  The `GetOwnerModuleFromTcpEntry` function is also a part of this same API, so it should be relatively similar in its implementation, although I can't find any examples.

The `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace seems to give all of the IP endpoints currently in use, but I can't seem to find anything that enables you to get any information about the actual processes using those endpoints in that namespace.  What you might try is the `System.Diagnostics` namespace. In there you have access to `Process` objects that have most of the information it looks like you're trying to get, including the PID and name (although you might have to fight with permissions issues on some of the process names).  I ran a quick test with the following and compared it to a `netstat -a -n -b -o` I had piped to a text file, and it seems to be a decent match. And before anyone says anything, this ***IS*** crappy code, and I just threw it together for testing, so no flames, please ;).

```
Dim CurrentProcesses As System.Diagnostics.Process() = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses

For Each Proc As System.Diagnostics.Process In CurrentProcesses
    Try
        Debug.WriteLine("[" & Proc.Id.ToString & "] " & Proc.MainModule.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'An "Access Denied" exception may be thrown on the Proc.MainModule.ToString, but
        'you can still get the PID for the process.
        Debug.WriteLine("[" & Proc.Id.ToString & "] Cannot get module name")
    End Try
Next Proc
```

The last alternative I can come up with would be to actually call a command line from code (using `Shell` or `Process.Start`) and run `netstat` and either pipe it to a text file, or read it into memory.  From there, you can parse the results.  An example of this is (taken from a [question on Experts-Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_27381134.html)):

```
Dim process As New Process()
Dim output As String = String.Empty

process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
process.StartInfo.FileName = "netstat"
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a -n -b -o"
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = False
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
process.Start()
process.WaitForExit(5000)

output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
MessageBox.Show(output)
```

Obviously this method requires a lot more code for the parsing of the `output` string, but it would provide you with the exact information received from the `netstat` command.

Comment: G_Hosa_Phat i knew about extracting the results from netstat and parsing it, but sometimes it is taking so much time that it hangs i am looking for a replacement because it is not a good way to shell netstat every 5 seconds for example..thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, it didn't seem like a good solution to me either.  It was just the last option I could come up with.  Try the `System.Diagnostics` namespace I mentioned above, and see if that helps.  The code example I offered is a little oversimplified, but it might be the best option.  That way you don't have to mess with API calls or making a bunch of unnecessary `Shell` calls.